# Hide the @ (at) symbol at the beginning of a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

One very nice feature of the StackExchange network is the ability for User A to address a comment to a previous commenter B using the `@username` syntax, and expect B to receive a notification. However, I cannot be the only user who finds all the `@` symbols, which have no part in grammatical English, something of an eyesore. I suspect certain sites in the network will have a large number of people who share my point of view.

Fundamentally, it seems to me, the `@` symbol in these posts is an instruction to the software, rather than an actual part of the sentence directed to humans.  It is similar to the `**` in `**This text would be rendered in bold if it were not in backticks.**`.  As such, would it not make sense to hide the actual symbol when the text is rendered?

I know that some people (especially those who use twitter extensively) may have become accustomed to treating the `@` symbol as a semantic part of a sentence (if twitter even has sentences?), but grammatical English has much more sightly alternatives for identifying nouns of direct address. I imagine other languages do also.

---

Possible clarification: I am suggesting that the software should render a valid `@<name>` construct at the beginning of a comment simply as `<name>`, possibly italicized or underlined or in bold. In particular, only the `@` symbol would be hidden, not the name following it.

This would have the added bonus that when an invalid address was used, it would be obvious to the commenter by the preservation of the `@` symbol, allowing for immediate revision. I will, however, admit that the software's existing facilities are already quite good at making sure valid addresses are used.

Comment: One advantage of showing the `@` symbols is that it teaches new users how to use this functionality.

Comment: @hammar: There's also a banner that comes up explaining this when you write a comment for the first time on a site.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if the existence of an answer with at least five upvotes will prevent this question from being automatically deleted as it accumulates downvotes (and a few upvotes, but mostly downvotes)? If possible, I would like it to remain a matter of public record that this suggestion was proposed and that the community as a whole was strongly against it, so that others of my persuasion will at least know not to blame the people in charge of the software.

Comment: Yes, but honestly, how many users do you think a) read that banner, b) understand it and c) remember it?

Comment: No, this won't be deleted if it's answered (i.e. has one answer with positive score).

Comment: @slhck: Thanks for your second comment. Concerning your first: the banner seems to come up for more than the first comment--I'm still seeing it on this meta site. I think the software creators have done there job well in coming up with a brief, clear, and prominent banner that people will actually understand, and making sure it comes up enough times that they will learn the (easy) instructions before it vanishes.

Comment: Unfortunately, experience tells me otherwise. I tend to keep a list of questions I want to follow, and sometimes when I reload those days later, I find comments that were meant to address me, but did not notify me because the author forgot to use the @, or didn't mention my username either. It happens all the time. While I'm a firm believer that the notification rules are too complicated, it doesn't seem like they're going to change it, so *even though* there is information on how to use it, we could do better in that regard.

Comment: @slhck: Just to play devil's advocate, I will point out that at least a few of the new users who omitted the `@` but did include your username may have gagged on including such a thing in their sentences: I certainly did, the first few times I tried to use it.

Comment: More seriously, the proper time for new users to start experimenting with `@` symbols is once they start to experience the notification system and want to be able to send notifications to others; and unless I miss my guess, the banner will still be there at that point to guide them.

Answer (score 9):

There are several advantages of using `@` (and keeping it shown):

- It's what users expect. Many sites (the famous one being Twitter) use the `@` symbol as a designation for notification.
- By displaying it, new users easily catch up.
- Staying consistent, you wrote a character, that character is shown. `@` isn't a part of Markdown, it's not like `**Bold text**`, where you explicitly expect the text to be bold.

If don't find it much of an "eye sore" as you do, apparently. I don't see a reason to hide it.

Comment: Well, whether something is an eyesore is a matter of taste and experience--when you see something often enough, it becomes part of the background, so I do expect e.g. twitter users to differ on this point. James Joyce believed quotation marks were an eyesore.

Comment: Indeed, and seeing that your suggestion was downvoted 11 times (as opposed to 3 times it was upvoted), looks like most of the community disagrees with your point of view.

Comment: The use of non-markdown modifications is not inconsistent with the StackExchange network; at least one large site, Math.SE, uses MathJax.

Comment: Concerning the votes: Gathering such information is the point of posting such questions, is it not? I also can't help but wonder if different domains within the StackExchange network would have different opinions on the matter.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: You can try posting at the respective site's meta and see what happens, but I doubt you'll get that much variation.

Comment: I asked on meta.stackexchange because so far as I can see, this is an issue that would not be allowed to vary among different domains within the network. That has not changed.